# Upload data to Sharepoint from Databricks using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, databricks, access-token, office365api

I have a requirement where I need to upload data from Databricks into a CSV format in a SharePoint folder. I am using the Client ID and Client Secret provided by the admin, but I am getting below error:

> ValueError: Acquire app-only access token failed.
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='adponline.sharepoint.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /folder/folder11 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))

My Requirement is to be able to upload the CSV file to SharePoint folder successfully.

Code which is giving Token Error:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files import file
from office365.sharepoint.files.creation_information import FileCreationInformation
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 

# SharePoint site URL and credentials
sharepoint_config = {
        'url': 'https://online.sharepoint.com/sites/Folder1',
        'client_id': 'clientid-Cliendid-cliendid',
        'client_secret': 'clientsecret',
}

library_url = '/folderpath'

file_name = 'Test.csv'
df = sqlContext.sql("""Select column1 , column2 from Table1 LIMIT 10 """)
#Convert the DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
#Convert the Pandas DataFrame to CSV
csv_data = pandas_df.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8')

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=sharepoint_config['url'])
print('Acquire the token...')
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=sharepoint_config['client_id'], client_secret=sharepoint_config['client_secret'])
print('Establishing connection...')
ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_config['url'], ctx_auth)
response = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(library_url).upload_file(file_name, csv_data).execute_query()

if response:
    print("Data uploaded successfully to SharePoint.")
else:
    print("Failed to upload data to SharePoint")
```

I tried other forums where they mentioned I can use the below code to get the token and pass it to above code. I am new to Pyspark and Databricks and totally unsure on how to get this done.

```
import msal
import json
import logging
import requests
import ast
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
tenant_id = 'Provide sample TenantID' 
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "engineering", key = "key"),
    client_credential=dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "engineering", key = "key"),
    authority=authority)
scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes, account=None)


#TOKEN VALID FOR ONLY 1 HOUR
if not result:
    print(
"No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from Azure Active Directory.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
if "access_token" in result:
    print("Access token is " + result["access_token"])
    now = datetime.now()
    refresh = now + timedelta(hours=-7,minutes = 50)
    print("Refresh Time: ", refresh)
```

Comment: I would like to know if this is possible also, for now I use databricks to prep the data ad a logic app to sync to sharepoint.